# How to load an additional style sheet in CKFinder?

Tags: css, ckfinder

I want to apply some customised styles to CKFinder - just small changes on top of the stock kama skin like background colours and fonts. To date I've edited app.css directly, but it's annoying as it means I have to merge changes very carefully when updating CKFinder.

Building a customised skin isn't any better as I would still need to merge the entire skin for updates.

How can I get CKFinder to load an extra style sheet so I can keep my changes separate and thus upgrade-resistant?